# Select by Location (Between two layers) - ArcObjects C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, select-by-location, spatial-filter

I have two Point [Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureClass.htm)es - Say FC1 and FC2 - added in the current map

I want to Select Features from FC1 that intersect with Features of FC2

This can be easily done with ArcMap's [Select By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) (Providing FC1 in target layer, and FC2 in source layer)

However, when I'm trying to do it in ArcObjects, using [IFeatureClass.Search Method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureClass_Search.htm) and following [this example](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#9181377e-d5b7-42f3-9767-556ae5834288.htm) I have the following code

```
public ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor PerformSpatialQuery(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry searchGeometry, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriSpatialRelEnum spatialRelation, System.String whereClause)
{
  // create a spatial query filter
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter spatialFilter=new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.SpatialFilterClass();

  // specify the geometry to query with
  spatialFilter.Geometry=searchGeometry;

  // specify what the geometry field is called on the Feature Class that we will be querying against
  System.String nameOfShapeField=featureClass.ShapeFieldName;
  spatialFilter.GeometryField=nameOfShapeField;

  // specify the type of spatial operation to use
  spatialFilter.SpatialRel=spatialRelation;

  // create the where statement
  spatialFilter.WhereClause=whereClause;

  // perform the query and use a cursor to hold the results
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter queryFilter=new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();
  queryFilter=(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter)spatialFilter;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor featureCursor=featureClass.Search(queryFilter, false);

  return featureCursor;
}
```

In this function, I have to provide a feature class and a [IGeometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGeometry.htm) as parameters, rather than two Feature Classes similar to [Select By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm)

Is there any other method, that simply takes two Feature Classes as whole and return the intersecting geometry from one Feature class? Or do I have to Iterate through the complete Feature Class and provide each point's geometry one by one?

Comment: One important thing to note is that selecting points with points mostly returns less points than it should, often even an empty selection, as geometries must *precisely* match to select.. I use ITopologicalOperator to buffer the selecting point by a very small amount and use the buffer polygon to do the actual selection; the value of *very small amount* is subjective, 1mm in a projected coordinate system seems to work well, selecting the matches and not including non-matches, 1e-07 for geographic works OK for me - experiment a bit and see what values work for you.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for the suggestion. Although my layers on which I am performing the "select" are basically the same layers. One layer is from a geometric network, and the other is the source layer from which the geometric network was created. But I will still look into using buffers and check the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by iterating through my feature class and adding all the points to a [MultiPoint](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#Multipoint.htm). 
Then I casted this multipoint into [IGeometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGeometry.htm) and sent it to the function.

Code: (I already had a tracedJunct[] array of the points of FC2 in the code which got useful)

```
Multipoint searchGeom_MultiPoint = new Multipoint();
for (int i = 0; i < juncCount; i++)
    searchGeom_MultiPoint.AddPoint((IPoint)tracedJunct[i]);

IGeometry searchGeom = (IGeometry) searchGeom_MultiPoint;
```

Let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: You can use IMap.SelectByShape on each feature and set the ISelectionEnvironment.CombinationMethod = esriSelectionResult.esriSelectionResultAdd. It probably won't be noticeably faster without a ton of features, but it will be cleaner.

Comment: That's very similar to the method I use, I am assuming you set searchGeom.SpatialReference after casting from the multipoint.. when using polylines/polygons often it's best to use ITopologicalOperator.Union to make a *super geometry* for selection; as @danielm suggests you can also iterate the selecting geometries (point, line or polygon), starting with an empty ISelectionSet (IFeatureClass.Select with esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionEmpty) Combine with esriSetOperation.esriSetUnion for each selecting geometry then create a cursor with ISelectionSet.Search (null,false,featureCursor).